# How to enclose a gridview row into anchor a tag?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with several rows. Each row has value for each column. When the user hover the gridview, I want each row to appear like one anchor tag, so that when clicked anywhere in the row, the result depends on the value of the row's id.

Instead of having each cell contain a link, I want the entire row to behave like a anchor tag.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the rows in to clickable hyperlink but it will have to write extra code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{ 
  e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "javascript:window.location='thepageyou want to post';";
  e.Row.Style["cursor"] = "pointer";
}
}
```

Comment: This won't work well with users who like to middle click and have the link open in a new tab. It will capture all clicks and redirect the current page regardless of the mouse button selected